# How can I print value of a key in a dictionary as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .csv file that I am supposed to read as a dictionary. Each key should be a string, while the value of that key should be a list.

The actual csv file:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa2Kt.png)

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

```
import csv
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 2 :
    print("Usage: csvToDict.py <filename>")
    sys.exit(1)

file_name = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_name, "r") as file :
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        for key in row:
            print(row[key], end='')
        print()
```

With this code, it prints all rows as values (except the header, which is treated as a key)

My output:

[image: My Output]

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Expected output as a picture is hard to read. Please provide example in code.

Comment: Sorry for bad quality, it was provided to me like this. The output is the same as values represented in csv file, except that the very first column has no quotes and is represented as this: 
CO2 per capita - [ '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', ... ]
Afghanistan - [ ... ]
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first column value to be the key and rest be printed as value. You can achieve it in this way:

```
with open(file_name, "r") as file :
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        line_items = []
        for key in row:
            line_items.append(row[key])
        print("{} - ".format(line_items[0]) + "['" + "','".join(line_items[1:]) + "']")
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. However, how do I proceed to do the same with the fieldnames? i have "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" when i assign fieldN = reader.fieldnames.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to get ALL values of a given column in as a list.

If that's the case something like this should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

all_values = defaultdict(list)

with open(file_name, "r") as file :
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        for key, value in row.items():
            all_values[key].append(value)
```

Comment: I tried this implementation and it prints head to head, from top down, the collumns of the csv file. Instead, i want the output to have the same looks as in the csv file, with the first column treated as a collection of keys, and the remaining columns as values for each key in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/). It's designed to read values from .csv files and it's widely used in data science.

Comment: For this assignment, I am forbidden to use pandas. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:``
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    co2Emmisions= {reader.fieldnames[0]: reader.fieldnanes[1:]}
    for r in reader.reader:
        co2Emmisions[r[0]]= r[1:]
    print(co2Emmisions)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this :

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    countries = {}
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        # row[0] is your index and row[1:] all the other values
        countries[row[0]] = row[1:]
        print(countries[row[0]])
```